# Inverse of a exponential function

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function, inverse-function

I try to calculate the inverse of the following exponential function (it's a CDF):  $$ f(x) = { 1 \over 3} e^{-x/2} + { 2 \over 3} e^{-x/4}  $$

I used a website to calculate it, they provided me the following: $$f^{-1}(x) = 4\cdot \ln\left({\sqrt{3x+1} +1 \over x}\right) + 4 \cdot \ln(3), $$ which seems to be correct. I now try to understand the way it was calculated but I can't figure it out.

I started with:

\begin{align}
y &= { 1 \over 3} e^{-x/2} + { 2 \over 3} e^{-x/4}\\
y &= 3 \cdot ( e^{-x/2} + 2 \cdot e^{-x/4} )\\
\ln(y) &= \ln(3 \cdot ( e^{-x/2} + 2 \cdot e^{-x/4} ))\\
\ln(y) - \ln(3) &= \ln( e^{-x/2} + 2 \cdot e^{-x/4} )
\end{align}

At this point I tried $\ln(a + c) = \ln(a) + \ln(1 + { c \over a})  $ which gave me:

\begin{align}
\ln(y) - \ln(3) &= -{x \over 2} + \ln\left(1 + 2 \cdot {e^{-x/4} \over e^{-x/2}  }\right)\\
&= -{x \over 2} + \ln(1 + 2 \cdot {e^{x/4}})
\end{align}
At this point, I'm stuck. Any help is appreciated.

Regards

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hint. Let $z=e^{-x/4}$ and solve the quadratic equation with respect to $z$.
$$y = { 1 \over 3} e^{-x/2} + { 2 \over 3} e^{-x/4}={ 1 \over 3} z^2 + { 2 \over 3} z\Leftrightarrow (z+1)^2=1+3y.$$

P.S. As pointed out by Yves Daoust, starting from the hint we easily find
$$x=f^{-1}(y)=-4\log\left(\sqrt{3y+1}-1\right)$$
which can be written also in the following way
\begin{align}
x=f^{-1}(y)&=-4\log\left(\sqrt{3y+1}-1\right)=4\log\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3y+1}-1}\right)\\
&=4\log\left(\frac{\sqrt{3y+1}+1}{(3y+1)-1}\right)
=4\log\left(\frac{\sqrt{3y+1}+1}{y}\right)-4\log(3).
\end{align}
So there is a missing minus sign in your formula. Note that $f(0)=1$ and therefore $f^{-1}(1)=0$.

Comment: Interestingly, the hint is preferred over the full answer. (Don't worry, I am not jealous.)

Comment: This answer was just a little bit faster and was sufficient to progress. But you are correct; in general, I should have accepted the complete answer since it will be more helpful for others. I will keep this in mind for future questions. 

I have a follow-up question on this topic. The website's solution has an additional part where the first log is divided by x and a second term (4 * log(3)). Where does this come from? 

Should I ask this in an additional question, or is it ok to add it as a comment?

Comment: @WiPU Is it clear now?

Comment: Yes, much clearer, thank you very much. I need to practice more; this transformation was not visible to me.

Answer (score 3):

Let $z:=e^{-x/4}$. We can write the equation as

$$3y=z^2+2z.$$

The solution of this quadratic equation is

$$z=\pm\sqrt{3y+1}-1$$

or

$$x=-4\log\left(\sqrt{3y+1}-1\right)$$ because the negative solution must be rejected.